# I Got some error msgs after "Build Successful" while installing React-native on my windows

Tags: android, react-native, installation, windows-7-x64

I've spent over 5 days on this (trying to install react-native on win 7). Finally achieved success only to see a few errors again after the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL":

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3 mins 18.927 secs
Running C:\Users\Romeo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 
emulator-
5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 
(C:\Users\Romeo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/plat
form-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n 
com.albums/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.albums/.MainActivity }
events.js:163
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Pls, What could be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Got it! Finally.**

After spending many hours researching and trying out many solutions, I solved it.

**Solution:**

*if you see a red/orange error screen on your emulator/Android device with the error message above, just do the following:*

**1)** Open a new command prompt.

**2)** Enter your project's file directory (e.g mine is: `cd C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\MyProject`) or wherever you saved yours and press "enter"

**3)** Then type: `react-native start` and hit "Enter", it will run for a few seconds.

**4)** After it's done running, press the `"reload"` button/text on your red screen emulator/device. Your cmd will automatically upload the javascript to your emulator.
After it's complete, your react native will be SET!
THAT'S ALL

`Important:`
Keep the new command prompt window running while developing any project.

You can open it at any time by running the command prompt (run as administrator) and following **step 2 & 3**. 
*Without this running packager*, your changes will not take effect on your simulator, you'll see an error page.